# Are water exercises in a mikva allowed?

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira, mikvah-ritual-bath, sport-athletics

Is there any problem with doing water exercises in a man-made structure designated as a mikva (if, for example, you are alone there). (Obviously in a natural mikva, such as a river or sea, is okay.)

Please provide a source.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect it should be prohibited?

Comment: yes. once read in a book on a mekubal (Yosef Dayan ztl), who states that it was akin to mekatzetz b'netiot, but there was no source.

Comment: @ray What is " mekatzetz b'netiot" is it a prohibition? If so, perhaps mention it in the question.